# Images not showing on Github in Readme.md file

Tags: github, editor, markdown, readme

Every time I drag and drop images into the Issue page of the project on Github and then copy the link to the Readme.md file. This usually works but if I have some more complex tags then images won't display, instead the link will be displayed.
  
 This is how it looks like in the [Markdown Editor](https://jbt.github.io/markdown-editor/):
[image: Markup]
  
  

 And this is how it looks like on Github(live):
[image: live]
  
  
 Note that the MarkDown editor displays the images as expected:
[image: displays them]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to nest Markdown inside block-level HTML (specifically `<details>`¹). In the original implementation, this [doesn't work by design](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> Note that Markdown formatting syntax is not processed within block-level HTML tags. E.g., you can’t use Markdown-style `*emphasis*` inside an HTML block.

If you are using an implementation that respects this decision, you should be able to use HTML syntax:

```
<details>
  <summary>Some summary</summary>
  <img alt="Description" src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/foo/bar/baz.png">
</details>
```

However, newer specs (most notably GitHub Flavored Markdown and CommonMark) *do* allow Markdown in block-level elements as long as they are separated by whitespace.

If you are using a modern implementation, try this:

```
<details>
  <summary>Some summary</summary>

  ![Description](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/foo/bar/baz.png)

</details>
```

---

¹[Note that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)

> "block-level" is not technically defined for elements that are new in HTML5