# Images not loading on any Github Repository or README

Tags: github

I have been observing that whenever I visit a Github README, the images don't load. First I thought it might be server error but it persisted even after a few days. This is not just limited to viewing images in README files but also as assets as well. Other images like profile pictures or thumbnails load properly or when images are called inside README's using HTML  tags. But not standalone images.

[On opening independant images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRk1K.png)

[No images load in README](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuTQF.png)

I thought there might be an issue with previewing the images on the README, so I tried to open the images independently but when I try to download the image, the page just keeps on loading but nothing happens. I have tried this with different repositories both private and public and on different browsers ie: Brave, Chrome and Safari on both my laptop and mobile device. But the same problem persists.

Is it something related to my account or network or ISP or is it something else. Can anyone please point out what might be the reason or what steps can I take.

Any response is appreciated!

Comment: Probably something wrong with the image paths. Please provide an example of how you're referencing your images in the Readme

Comment: @AndriiBodnar I have an assets folder which has png files. And they are referenced in the following way `![Sink-main](assets/sink-main.png)`

Comment: The way how you reference the image is correct. But as I can see from the first screenshot - the image file is somehow broken. Try to reupload it

Comment: getting the same issue frequently, the images wont load sometimes on Readme or markdown files in GitHub, tried with chrome and Firefox on both my laptop and mobile on different repositories both private and public, after minutes of loading the images are showing broken, but the images exists, what may be the issue

Comment: I think I found a solution for my issue that is with the Jio internet connection in India, using a VPN or in my case changing the DNS servers to google (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4) and a re-connection WLAN solved the loading images issue.

Comment: Duplicate of [Images not showing on Github in Readme.md file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51458997/4450498)

Answer (score 2):

For me, after changing my DNS server to [google](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using) works.
Make sure you restart your router and then image loading issues will be fixed.

Use `8.8.8.8` or `8.8.4.4` for IPv4 or `2001:4860:4860::8888` or `2001:4860:4860::8844` for IPv6